# upgrade ICU and intl

Tags: linux, symfony, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

After installing Symfony 2 and check /config.php I got this notification:

intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (55.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)
To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.

How can I upgrade this?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a warning and you can safely ignore the message. I've response to similar questions on this. See this URL for more details:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007

Note: You'll also get the message when you run:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

The message will say it's an "Optional recommendation".

---

**EDIT #2**

Based on your comments. You need to upgrade ICU. Sounds like you might be on Debian, and it might be possible to upgrade. Try these commands.

```
yum list available |grep icu
```

This shows what packages are available and searches for "icu". The second column shows the version. If there is a version that shows "57.1", then you should be able to use `yum install` to install it. Otherwise you would have to build and install on your system, which is much more difficult to give you a definite answer.

Comment: Thank for response. 
I know it's "Optional recommendation" and I shouldn't panic but I've thought there is some easy way to upgrade this and chase this ugly notification away :)

Comment: See my EDIT #2 answer. I believe this should answer your question. You should click the checkmark besides my answer if it does.

Comment: As i said, I use ubuntu  - not Debian but I've tried to update ICU by command:
`$sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade icu-doc`
but it's give me a notification:
icu-doc is already the newest version (55.1-7).

I think it is as you said " much more difficult" to upgrade this to 57.1 So I'm going to ignore this.

Anyway thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi Pawel. `icu-doc` is not the right package. Is there any other options when you do a `yum search icu`. Ubuntu will be similar to Debian.